# Is there any method of getting detailed object information when using pdb to debug python script?

Tags: python, debugging, pdb

I am using `pdb` to debug a simple `python` script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

f = open("./hello.scala")
f.close()
```

The debug flow like this:

```
[root@localhost ~]# python -m pdb test.py
> /root/test.py(3)<module>()
-> f = open("./hello.scala")
(Pdb) n
> /root/test.py(4)<module>()
-> f.close()
(Pdb) p f
<open file './hello.scala', mode 'r' at 0x7f4d69aae8a0>
(Pdb) pp f
<open file './hello.scala', mode 'r' at 0x7f4d69aae8a0>
```

I want to check the detailed information of File object `f`, but I can only get the address of it. Is there any method of getting detailed object information when using `pdb` to debug `python` script?

Comment: What "detailed information" do you want? Something like all of the attributes, as returned by [`inspect.getmembers`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html)?'

Comment: @abarnert: I just wonder whether `pdb` can work as `gdb`: print all the members values of the object instance prettily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use most arbitrary Python expressions in pdb.

I don't know what "detailed object information" you're looking for, but in general, anything useful will be an attribute.

Since you know what type you've got (a `file`), and it's a builtin or stdlib type that comes with Python, you can [look it up in the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file-objects) and see what attributes it's guaranteed to have. For example, `file` objects have a `closed` attribute; to see that:

```
(Pdb) p f.closed
True
```

If you don't know what attributes you want, you can use the [`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html) module to help. For example:

```
(Pdb) import inspect
(Pdb) p inspect.getmembers(f, lambda x: not callable(x))
[('__doc__', "file(name[, mode[, buffering]]) -> file object\n\nOpen a file.  The mode can be 'r', 'w' or 'a' for reading (default),\nwriting or appending.  The file will be created if it doesn't exist\nwhen opened for writing or appending; it will be truncated when\nopened for writing.  Add a 'b' to the mode for binary files.\nAdd a '+' to the mode to allow simultaneous reading and writing.\nIf the buffering argument is given, 0 means unbuffered, 1 means line\nbuffered, and larger numbers specify the buffer size.  The preferred way\nto open a file is with the builtin open() function.\nAdd a 'U' to mode to open the file for input with universal newline\nsupport.  Any line ending in the input file will be seen as a '\\n'\nin Python.  Also, a file so opened gains the attribute 'newlines';\nthe value for this attribute is one of None (no newline read yet),\n'\\r', '\\n', '\\r\\n' or a tuple containing all the newline types seen.\n\n'U' cannot be combined with 'w' or '+' mode.\n"), ('closed', True), ('encoding', None), ('errors', None), ('mode', 'r'), ('name', 'temp.xml'), ('newlines', None), ('softspace', 0)]
```

If you want it pretty-printed, just use the [`pp`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html#debugger-commands) command instead of `p`:

```
(Pdb) pp inspect.getmembers(f, lambda x: not callable(x))
[('__doc__',
  "file(name[, mode[, buffering]]) -> file object\n\nOpen a file.  The mode can be 'r', 'w' or 'a' for reading (default),\nwriting or appending.  The file will be created if it doesn't exist\nwhen opened for writing or appending; it will be truncated when\nopened for writing.  Add a 'b' to the mode for binary files.\nAdd a '+' to the mode to allow simultaneous reading and writing.\nIf the buffering argument is given, 0 means unbuffered, 1 means line\nbuffered, and larger numbers specify the buffer size.  The preferred way\nto open a file is with the builtin open() function.\nAdd a 'U' to mode to open the file for input with universal newline\nsupport.  Any line ending in the input file will be seen as a '\\n'\nin Python.  Also, a file so opened gains the attribute 'newlines';\nthe value for this attribute is one of None (no newline read yet),\n'\\r', '\\n', '\\r\\n' or a tuple containing all the newline types seen.\n\n'U' cannot be combined with 'w' or '+' mode.\n"),
 ('closed', True),
 ('encoding', None),
 ('errors', None),
 ('mode', 'r'),
 ('name', 'temp.xml'),
 ('newlines', None),
 ('softspace', 0)]
```

---

As the docs explain up near the top:

> The `getmembers()` function retrieves the members of an object such as a class or module. The sixteen functions whose names begin with “is” are mainly provided as convenient choices for the second argument to `getmembers()`.

But you don't have to use those 16 functions, you can pass anything you want. As the `getmembers` docs say:

> Return all the members of an object in a list of (name, value) pairs sorted by name. If the optional *predicate* argument is supplied, only members for which the predicate returns a true value are included.

So, as an example, I wrote a custom function, `lambda x: not callable(x)`, which is true only for members that aren't callable. That means I won't get things like the `close` method, just things like the `closed` attribute.

If you don't understand `lambda`, it's a way to define simple functions in the middle of an expression. It's the same as if I'd written:

```
def my_function(x):
    return not callable(x)
```

… and then called `inspect.getmembers(f, my_function)`.

---

While we're at it, you may want to take a look at [IPython](http://ipython.org/), a replacement for the default Python interactive mode. Among other things, it gives you tab completion within Pdb (and within normal interactive sessions):

```
ipdb> n
--Return--
None
> /Users/abarnert/src/pt.py(2)<module>()
1     1 f = open('temp.txt')
----> 2 f.close()

ipdb> p f
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='temp.xml' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>
ipdb> p f.
f.buffer          f.fileno          f.newlines        f.seekable
f.close           f.flush           f.read            f.tell
f.closed          f.isatty          f.readable        f.truncate
f.detach          f.line_buffering  f.readline        f.writable
f.encoding        f.mode            f.readlines       f.write
f.errors          f.name            f.seek            f.writelines
ipdb> p f.
```

(Sorry for using Python 3 in that example transcript; my Python 2.7 is right in the middle of upgrading IPython...)

Comment: Awesome answer! If possible, could you explain a bit of 'lambda x: not callable(x)'?

Comment: @NanXiao: Sure, give me a sec.

Comment: @abarnert I believe you showed us output of ipdb, a separate debugger which uses Ipython.

Comment: @Alik: Yes, my last transcript is from ipdb. That's because it's part of the section that starts off with "While we're at it, you may want to take a look at IPython, a replacement for the default Python interactive mode", and is intended to show why he might want to use IPython.

Comment: @Alik: Or are you saying that I used IPython plus ipdb, rather than just IPython? If so, no; start up `ipython`, then `%run -d pt.py`, and you'll get that same prompt. I believe the separate `ipdb` module is only needed if you want to launch IPython's debugger from outside of IPython (from the middle of a script, or with a shell command).

Comment: Thank you for such a wonderful explanation. Learnt quite a thing from your explaination.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way I know to achieve this is by defining an alias in a `.pdbrc` file.

Here's [Ned's famous .pdbrc file](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/200704/my_pdbrc.html).

In it you can find the `pi` alias (short for "print instance"), which does pretty much what you're looking for.

There are other useful aliases there as well.

Very useful, highly recommended.